# Window function for rest the first value from Column1 against values of Column2

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I need to get the balance for a data that look like this:

The base tables:

```
DebtsHeader
Zone, Id, Date  , TotalDebt
1,     1, 10-Jan,       100
2,     2, 11-Jan,       200
2,     3, 11-Jan,       300

DebtsPayment
Debt, Date  , Pay
1,    10-Jan, 10
2,    11-Jan, 20
2,    12-Jan, 30
3,    11-Jan, 30
```

I have a view that join both and get this:

```
Zone, Debt, Date  , TotalDebt,  Pay
1,       1, 10-Jan,       100,   10
2,       3, 10-Jan,       500,   30
2,       2, 11-Jan,       500,   20
2,       2, 12-Jan,       500,   30
```

Now, I need to get the balance by zone & date, ej:

```
Zone, Date  , Balance
1,    10-Jan,      90
2,    10-Jan,     470
2,    11-Jan,     450
2,    12-Jan,     420
```

I can do this with imperative code, but wonder if window functions could make this work.

Comment: What data type is `Date`. That doesn't look like a valid date to me

Comment: Is a normal Date. I just reduce it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . If I had to guess, "ene" --> "Jan".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the window function `sum` here.

```
select zone, date, totaldebt-sum(pay) over(partition by zone order by date)
from your_view
```